# How to use pandas apply instead a list loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'market':['ES','UK','DE'],
                   'provider':['A','B','C'],
                   'item':['X','Y','Z']})
```

Then I have a list with the providers and the following loop:

```
providers_list = ['A','B','C']
for provider in providers_list:
  a = df.loc[df['provider']==provider]
```

That loop creates a dataframe for each provider, which later on I put into an excel. I would like to use the function apply for speed purposes. I have transformed the code like this:

```
providers_list = pd.DataFrame({'provider':['A','B','C']})
def report(provider):
 a = df.loc[df['provider']==provider]
providers_list.apply(report)
```

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 1190, in wrapper
>       raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled "
>
> ValueError: ('Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects',
>   'occurred at index provider')

Thanks

Comment: Do you need [`df.groupby('provider').apply(func)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) ?

Comment: @roganjosh There are no more packages right now. For testing purposes, I am just making the dataframe creation.

Comment: @roganjosh You are absolutely right. That's why before replying you I edited my question to include the full traceback, both with pandas and swifter. Sorry for the inconveniences and thanks.

 I have edited also the question avoiding swifter and just sticking to pandas apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apply` method is *generally inefficient*. It's nothing more than a glorified loop with some extra functionality. Instead, you can use `GroupBy` to cycle through each `provider`:

```
for prov, df_prov in df.groupby('provider'):
    df_prov.to_excel(f'{prov}.xlsx', index=False)
```

If you only want to include a *pre-defined* `list` of providers in your output, you can define a `GroupBy` object and iterate your list instead:

```
providers_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
grouper = df.groupby('provider')

for prov in providers_list:
    grouper.get_group(prov).to_excel(f'{prov}.xlsx', index=False)
```

If you're interested in speed for your process as a whole, I strongly advise you avoid Excel: exporting to `csv`, `csv.gz` or `pkl` will all be much more efficient. For large datasets, it's unlikely filtering your dataframe is your bottleneck when exporting to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with a milllion entries of each provider in under a second:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm

tqdm.pandas(desc="Progress:")


df = pd.DataFrame({'market':['ES','UK','DE']*1000000,
                   'provider':['A','B','C']*1000000,
                   'item':['X','Y','Z']*1000000})

grouped = df.groupby("provider")
providers_list = ['A','B','C']

for prov in tqdm(providers_list):
    frame_name = prov
    globals()[frame_name] = pd.DataFrame(grouped.get_group(prov))

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)

100%|██████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00,  9.59it/s]
```

Comment: Don't use `globals()` unnecessarily. It's poor practice.

Comment: Okay, do you know how to create the named DataFrames in a correct manner? I would edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Use a dictionary of dataframes (if necessary) instead.